# add text value to attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

this is a novice question

I have an attribute field that's missing a piece of information, i'd like to amend the attribute field like below:

This is the current attribute field:

"V:\Building & Development...."

and i'd like to add "\Engineering" to attribute field

"V:***\Engineering***\Building & Development...."

I have to make this change to 1441 attribute fields, not sure how to write the python script in the field calculator.  I'm doing this on ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop

Answer (score 3):

Using the Python parser in the field calculator:

Pre-logic script code:

```
def convert(x):
  a = x.split(":")
  return a[0] + ":\Engineering" + a[1]
```

---

```
convert(!text_field!)
```

---

You can also use an [UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) to do this

```
import arcpy

fc = r'path\to\your\fc'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "your_field") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] != None:
            a = row[0].split(":")
            row[0] = a[0] + ":\Engineering" + a[1]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

---